# How to extract a value from a csv in bash

Tags: bash

I have a csv file which contains a lot of rows as the one below.

```
,appOne      ,na    ,All,       ,All                                 ,All      ,   ,PORTNAME,21500,
```

I need to get that 21500 at the end in bash which is a port the process will be started on

The csv file also has columns and I would like to know where that 21500 is

the pseudocode would be something like this

```
get columns
split columns by ","
index = find where column = PORT 
get row 
split by ","
if i == index : return value
```

any suggestions ?

UPDATE:

```
SKIP,APP    ,REG,ENV,CLST, HST, INST, UID,PRM     ,VAL  ,COMMENTS
    ,appOne ,na ,All,    ,All ,All  ,    ,PORTNAME,21500,
```

Comment: I see a trailing comma after 21500: exactly which field contains the port? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: see my update. I was thinking doing a for loop to find the index of the VAL param and then use "cut -d ',' -d${INDEX}". would that work?

Comment: Does that mean you don't know what column it's in?

Comment: Assuming you have no need to handle escaped commas, `awk` would be appropriate. `bash` really isn't suitable for processing data like this.

Comment: Check out https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/ if you're open to tools

Answer (score 0):

temp.csv:

```
SKIP,APP    ,REG,ENV,CLST, HST, INST, UID,PRM     ,VAL  ,COMMENTS
    ,appOne ,na ,All,    ,All ,All  ,    ,PORTNAME,21500,
```

```sh
function field_index() {
  local field_name=$1
  local header

  read -a header
  for ((i = 0 ; i < ${#header[@]} ; i++)); do
    if [[ "${header[$i]}" =~ \s*"${field_name}"\s* ]]; then
      echo $i
      break
    fi
  done
}

port_field_index=$(field_index VAL < temp.csv)

function trim() {
  echo "$1" | xargs echo -n
}

(
  read _ # Skip header
  while IFS=',' read -a row; do
    trim "${row[$port_field_index]}" # Process port somehow
  done
) < temp.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using sed**

A simple `sed` expression using a capture group to collect the port number and delete all other text by reinserting the port number as a backreference is about as easy as anything else, e.g.

```
$ port=$(echo "KIP,APP    ,REG,ENV,CLST, HST, INST, UID,PRM     ,VAL  ,COMMENTS     ,appOne ,na ,All,    ,All ,All  ,    ,PORTNAME,21500," |
sed -E 's/^.*,([[:digit:]]+),.*$/\1/')
```

Which results in

```
$ echo "port = $port"
port = 21500
```

If there is guaranteed to be no characters after the last `','`, you can tighten up the expression by anchoring the end of string as:

```
sed -E 's/^.*,([[:digit:]]+),$/\1/'
```

**Using Parameter Expansion with Substring Removal**

Another pure-shell option is to use parameter expansion with substring removal to trim the last comma from the back end of the string and then trim all commas from the front end of the string, e.g.

```sh
line="KIP,APP    ,REG,ENV,CLST, HST, INST, UID,PRM     ,VAL  ,COMMENTS     ,appOne ,na ,All,    ,All ,All  ,    ,PORTNAME,21500,"
port="${line%,*}"      ## trim comma from back end
port="${port##*,}"     ## trim through the last comma from front end
echo "port = $port"
```

Which again results in:

```
port = 21500
```

The four standard parameter expansions with substring removal provide by POSIX shell are:

```
${var#pattern}      Strip shortest match of pattern from front of $var
${var##pattern}     Strip longest match of pattern from front of $var
${var%pattern}      Strip shortest match of pattern from back of $var
${var%%pattern}     Strip longest match of pattern from back of $var
```